# "Send to" insert statement like for mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a simple collection with many documents. (for the sake of simplicity all the documents are of the following structure:

```
{"name" : "some name"}
```

I would like to execute a query that will return a string that can be used as an "insert statement" for all these documents. for example the result is the following string:

```
'db.collection.insert({"name" : "first Item"});
db.collection.insert({"name" : "Second Item"});
....
db.collection.insert({"name" : "Last Item"})'
```

I will use that string in order to insert these documents to other mongoDB instances (I dont want to use export \ import)

Comment: A bit unclear what you are trying to do here, do you wish to write a JavaScript function (seeing that you have tagged this with the JS tag) that will return insert statements given an array of names?

Comment: @chridam Check my update please.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to pass around an array of `names` and use the same function throughout to insert into databases.

```
Promise.all(names.map(name => db.collection.insert(name:name)))
.then(() => console.log(all done));
```